# Delete only the relationship between tables, not the data

Tags: database, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using NHibernate for DB connection for the following classes:

```
Class A
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public List<B> InnerElements{get;set;}

}

Class B
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Description{get;set;}
   ...no reference to the parent
}
```

and in the DB i have As (to class A), Bs(to class b) and ABs tables where the table ABs has an autoincremented id, and the ids of A and B entities.

The configuration files for the classes are:

Class A

```
...other properties mapped
<bag name="InnerElements" table="ABs" cascade="all" inverse="true">
      <key column="AID" />
      <many-to-many class="B" column="BID"/>
    </bag>
```

and in the class B i dont have any refferences to class A.

When I remove an B element from the InnerElements from an entity of type A, and try to Save/Update the modified entity back to the DB, the inner ABs table remains unmodified. 
How can I change (in the config files or otherwise) to remove the entry from the inner table ? I dont want to remove any A or B entry from DB.

Thanks in advance,
Tamash

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `inverse="true"`. That attribute, which looks copy&pasted, means you are handling the relationship from the *other* side, which does not exist in this case.